# Probability that the bus will come before the train

Tags: probability

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

The bus arrives at the stop every 4 minutes and the train, which stops right next to the bus, every 6 minutes. What is the probability that a bus will come before the train? What is the probability of a bus or train coming in two minutes?

My attempt:

Sample space will represents all the stops of the train and bus for one hour: 15*10=150. But I do not know how to represent the probability of the events.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It may depend on whether the arrivals are independent Poisson processes or regular scheduled processes

Comment: @Henry they are independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not well formulated, but usually they mean that $X \sim U(0,4)$ and $Y\sim U(0,6)$, where X denotes the bus arrival time and Y the train arrival time. Your space is the rectangle $(0,4)\times(0,6)$. Bus comes before the train is the event $X<Y$, bus and train come within 2 minutes is $|X-Y|<2$. The probability of these is their area divided by the are of the full rectangle.

Edit: as Ben W pointed out the second event might be $\min(X,Y)<2$.

Comment: I think he's asking for $P(X\wedge Y\leq 2)$.  But your geometric idea will still work.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.

Comment: @Mick no, you understood it right.. so the probability of the first event is 14/24?

Comment: should be 16/24. (4*4/2 + 2*4)/24

Comment: @Mick Can you please explain, why? I think I am lost

Comment: @Mick why is there 4*4/2?

Comment: The area $\{(x,y)\in (0,4)\times (0,6):x<y\}$ consists of a right triangle with vertices $(0,0),(0,4),(4,4)$ and a rectangle $(0,4),(0,6),(4,4),(4,6)$.

Comment: Draw the $y=x$ line. Everything that's above this line admits $x<y$.

Comment: @Mick and the probability of the second one is 10/24?

Comment: Should be (24- 4×4/2 -2×2/2)/24=14/24